# Error when converting to char * to my custom class(MyString) object

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I am trying to write my own string class using the  library for preparing my exam .But I had this error saying that

```
main.cpp:9:22: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘const
 char [5]’ and ‘MyString’)
 MyString c = "Hola" + b;
```

My main is like this. It works file then "Hola" and b change place.

```
MyString b("Mundo\n");
MyString c = "Hola" + b;
```

I think it doesn't call the  constructor there .
My class has these in private.

```
char * _str
int _length
```

My constructor.

```
MyString::MyString(const char * str){

    int length = 0;
    for(char c = str[0]; c != '\0' ; c++)
        ++length;

    _length = length;
    _str = new char[length+1];

    strcpy(_str,str);

}
```

And my + overload

```
const MyString MyString::operator+(const MyString& mS) const{

    char * tempChar = new char[_length + mS._length];
    MyString tempStr(tempChar);
    delete[] tempChar;
    strcpy(tempStr._str,_str);
    strcat(tempStr._str,mS._str);

    return tempStr;
}
```

**Edit : I solved it by making operator+ a friend function but I want to know why**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you write

```
 MyString b{"Mundo\n"};
 MyString c = b + "Hola";
```

string literal will be sent your operator+ function paremeter, and MyString object created with "Holla"(You can test it with write a text in your constructor).

Besides, when you didn't write your friend function and write

```
 MyString b{"Mundo\n"};
 MyString c = "Holla" + b;
```

compiler will search function which has first parameter is const char * and can't find.(and no match error show this). this is the reason for writing friend function.
I hope you can understand reason